# Converting PDF files at a given density when page parameter is set - ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, exec, imagick, imagemagick-convert

If the page parameter is set, conversion of PDF files at a given density outputs blank pages.

```
"convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300  $myfiles -page A4  -gravity center test.pdf"
```

If I omit `page` parameter from the command, I get appropriate output but at `72dpi` default resolution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A4 page size is 595 x 842. So in ImageMagick you could try

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 $myfiles +repage -resize 595x842  test.pdf
```

That will make an A4 pixel dimension image with 300 dpi. You could also do

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 $myfiles +repage -resize 595x842  -density XX test.pdf
```

Where XX is the dpi you want when printing the image of that size.

I added +repage to remove any input image virtual canvas, since you did not specify what format images you are using for $myfiles. Without +repage, that could have caused a large bit of white space at the top of your result.

Note it is always best and most helpful to provide your ImageMagick version and platform when asking questions about its use.

Comment: You first command returns duplicate pages of different sizes where `density ` effects on the canvas but not on the object.  On the other hand your second command returns unexpected duplicate but same size pages  where `density ` implies to the canvas but not to the object. Thus, Both the commands return blurry small image on large canvas.

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to tweak the command I found that a set `density` (`i.e, density 300`) with a given `page` parameter actually sets the density of the `-page A4` but not the converted `object` on page as the set density can't actually determine resolution of the `-page A4` to which it shall be applicable. As a result, the command returns blurry or blank image on set page.

However, `extent` parameter is what, which actually outputs the appropriate image as it is possible to set the page resolution with this parameter at a predefined density. The following example will make it absolutely clear.

Resolution of A4 size page at `300 dpi` is 2480x3508, thus correct command for a set density like `300 dpi` shall be:

```
"convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 $myfiles -gravity center -extent 2480x3508 test.pdf"
```

Resolution of A4 size page at `72 dpi` is 595x842, thus correct command for a set density like `72 dpi` shall be:

```
"convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 72 $myfiles -gravity center -extent 595x842 test.pdf"
```